# Yandex Map Api (Button)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Можно ли программным путем в Yandex Map Api, реализовать клик по созданной кнопке в пределах другой функции?

```
var addPlacemarkButtonSphere = new ymaps.control.Button({
        data: { title: 'Геозона(круг)', content: 'Геозона', id: 'test' },
        options: { float: 'right', selectOnClick: false }
 });
myMap.controls.add(addPlacemarkButtonSphere );
```

Имеется функция, которая принимает аргументы. В зависимости от аргумента, нужно произвести нажатие по той или иной кнопке, которая есть в карте, после ее инициализации и отрисовки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждой кнопки есть поле [`events`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.Button-docpage/#control.Button__properties-summary) у этого поля есть метод [`fire()`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IEventManager-docpage/#method_detail__fire)

Будет достаточно вызвать

```
myButton1.events.fire('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, все работает.

```
addPlacemarkButtonLine.events.add('click', function () {
//Функция
});
//Программный вызов
addPlacemarkButtonLine.events.fire('click');
```